# How to match latin letters + their accented versions?

Tags: search, unicode, pattern

`\a` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z]` so it matches only non-accented letters.

I know of [`[=name-of-equivalence-class=]`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%5B%3D%3D%5D), so I can clearly use something like `\(\a\|[[=a=][=e=][=i=][=o=][=u=]]\)`, but I was wondering whether there was a more fundamental solution, such as an option to automatically match every element of the equivalance class for each character in the pattern.

The reason why I would have expected a less hand-crafted solution is that other options doing something similar exist, such as [`\c`/`\C`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cc) and [`\Z`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CZ).

I haven't found anything in `:help pattern`.

Comment: The trouble is that not all accented characters are composites. `à` is `U+00e0` but `à` is `U+0061` + `U+0300`: `[=a=]` and `\Za` match the latter but not the former. Handling both scenarios would mean doing what `[=…=]` and `\Z` do, *plus* matching against all the single character variants of those pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the [`\k`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Ck) character class, which matches anything that is in [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27), which can in turn be `set iskeyword=@`, where the meaning of `@` is explained at [`isfname`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27):

> If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE are included.  Normally these are the characters a to z and A to Z, plus accented characters.

Which is precisely what I need.

So one way to accomplish the task is to use `\k` instead of [`\a`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Ca) and `set iskeyword=@` when the behavior described in the question is needed, e.g. when entering search mode.